# Where does the route /json/syncreply come from in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I'm trying to send a request to a third party api using this DTO:

```cs
[Route("log_entries", "GET")]
public class MyRequest: IReturn<MyResponse>
{
}
```

The client request:

```cs
string uri = "https://..../api/v1"
var jsonClient = new JsonServiceClient(uri);

// This works
var response = client.Get<MyResponse>("/log_entries");

// Does not work
var response = client.Send(new MyRequest());
```

I'm getting a `Not Found` response currently. When I send to `http://` using Fiddler, I can see the
path `/json/syncreply` is added i.e. `../api/v1/json/syncreply`> I am looking to understand where this comes from and how to ensure my request is sent on the right path.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/json/syncreply` is route that is defined in ServiceStack API, as a method for sending DTOs without having to provide a specific route for the given DTO, in other words a ServiceStack host would make a route based on the the type name of `MyRequest`, which can be resolved by ServiceStack clients using the `Send` method.

## 3rd party API don't use `Send`

As you are consuming a 3rd party API using the `ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient` and their API is not ServiceStack based, then the `Send` method will not work, because their server API does not have appropriate routes.

The `Send` method only works for consuming ServiceStack API, because this is a ServiceStack specific feature.

## Use the Request DTO

You should be making your request like this, note the `Get<T>` where `T` is the request object, `MyRequest` not `MyResponse`.

```cs
MyResponse response = client.Get<MyRequest>();
```

And also add a slash at the front of your route declaration on your DTO:

```cs
[Route("/log_entries", "GET")]
public class MyRequest: IReturn<MyResponse>
{
}
```

## tldr;

For 3rd party API that is not a ServiceStack Service, you need to use the appropriate VERB methods such as `Get`, `Post`, `Put` etc, so the route defined on the DTO is used, not the `json/syncreply` route, therefore simply avoid the `Send` method.